# Vue 'watch' problem: Declaration emit for this file requires using private name 'handler'. An explicit type annotation may unblock declaration emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use 'watch' in the component, just like:

```
watch: {
        config:{
            handler: function(){
                this.colorAnalysis = this.$props.config;
            },
            deep: true,
            immediate: true
        },
```

It can work, but show message below:

> Declaration emit for this file requires using private name 'handler'.
> An explicit type annotation may unblock declaration emit.

I can not figure out what's the problem, and how to prevent this situation.
Please give me some directions.Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to watch props, vue watches them. You can directly use them. However, you can not change them in a children.

Comment: @gguney I need to assign a variable to the prop, then watch the variable, no matter changed from prop or any other way.
How can I do?
```
watch:{
    config() {
      this.status = this.$props.config
    },
   status() {
      if(this.status===null) this.status=this.$props.config;
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not figure out the reason.
But when I change format to:

```
watch: {
    config() {
        this.colorAnalysis = this.$props.config;
    },
}
```

the message disappeared!